# How can restrict two decimal places only in Input Number

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

How can I given restriction only to accept two decimal place or how can I format with only two decimal place . I  tried with model  RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$" and I tried @step 01 and tabindex 7, still not working , we can give more than two numbers for decimal . Here is the code

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.attendanceLogList[i].NormalHrs, new
 {
       @class = "form-control input-sm emphrs",
       @style = columnstyle,
       @Value = Model.attendanceLogList[i].NormalHrs,
       @type = "number",
       @step = ".01",
       onchange = "CalculateTotal(this);"
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the onchange event `CalculateTotal(this);` is a javascript function. IMHO, applying the javascript as below into your Razor snippet, in the same way, should work, FYI.

```js
function fixDecimal(e) {
  return e.value = e.value.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" onkeyup="fixDecimal(this)" />
```